# How to declare and save the values in a data class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I am trying to learn Flutter and Supabase and still trying to learn its concepts coming from imperative programming. I am trying to save the returned results from the database query. Here are my current code snippets:

```
class Respondent {
  String id;
  String householdNumber;
  String lastname;
  String firstname;
  String? middlename;
  ...

  Respondent(
      {required this.id,
      required this.householdNumber,
      required this.lastname,
      required this.firstname,
      this.middlename,
      ...});

  static Respondent fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Respondent(
        id: json['id'],
        householdNumber: json['household_number'],
        lastname: json['lastname'],
        firstname: json['firstname'],
        middlename: json['middlename'],
        ...
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'id': id,
        'household_number': householdNumber,
        'lastname': lastname,
        'firstname': firstname,
        'middlename': middlename,
        ...
      };
}
```

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String respondentId;

  const HomePage(this.respondentId, {super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
  late Respondent respondent;

  Future<void> getRespondent(String id) async {
    try {
      final response =
          await supabase.from('respondents').select().eq('id', id).single();

      setState(() {
        if (mounted) {
          print('Response' + response.toString());

          respondent = Respondent.fromJson(response);
          print('Respondent' + respondent.lastname);
          //respondent.lastname = response['last_name'].toString();
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Unexpected Error'),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getRespondent(widget.respondentId);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('XXX'),
      ),
      body: Text(widget.respondentId),
    );
  }
}
```

Coming after a successful login, I am trying to store the ***response*** results to the ***respondent*** variable. I tried printing the response and it was correct but assigning the values to the respondent variable is not working, it was **null**. If I tried to individually assign the values, it still does not work. A clue I guess is that if I tried to print the respondent values in a Text widget in the build method, I will get a `LateInitializationError`. Also I would like to have the respondent object be available to the whole application once it has values saved. How should I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To prevent late initialization error, don't declare `respondent` as a late variable. Declare is as a nullable variable instead (`Respondent? respondent`). Also, check if the local variable `response` in `getRespondent` is null or not.

Comment: It is not nullable. As mentioned, the screen before is a login page.  It will only redirect if there is an existing account. In the login screen, it will get the id and it will be passed to retrieve the rest of the data in the home page.  I have printed the response (terminal) and it is returning the result

Comment: Then why are you storing `respondent` in this page? You would only do that if you need to pass `respondent` to a widget in _this_ page. Anyway, you would still need nullable because you can't expect a `Future` to completes before the build happens. While it's computing, let the variable that you want to assign be a nullable, which forces you to handle the null case. Don't make it late, as it will cause error if the value is read before it's actually initialized.

Comment: I will be using the using the respondent variable in the page. I am just doing it step by step: query the Supabase db, check the response, store the response in a variable (this should be available to all pages) then show it/print the values in the screen.

Comment: In that case, it's mandatory for you to make it nullable, and render the widget conditionally based on the nullability. Or you can let it be a `Future` and use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to render the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest making a named constructor rather than static method that returns an object:

**From**

```
  static Respondent fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Respondent(
        id: json['id'],
        householdNumber: json['household_number'],
        lastname: json['lastname'],
        firstname: json['firstname'],
        middlename: json['middlename'],
        ...
      );
```

**To**

```
 Respondent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    id = json['id'],
    householdNumber = json['household_number'],
    lastname =  json['lastname'],
    firstname = json['firstname'],
    middlename = json['middlename'];
```

using the initializer list.

and one more important thing: **check the correctness of the keys eg:** *'lastname,...'* **of the map you are trying to deserialize.**

Comment: I double checked the keys and one was incorrect. It did not produced an error message so I did not notice it. This solved the issue.  Also, how should the code snippet be when making it nullable, besides having a ?